# How to match multiple words in multiple lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a multiline text, e.g.

```
word1 in line1
     word2 in line2
  word3 in line 3
```

I need to see if two words present in whole text (AND operator). I tried something like:

```
/^.*(?=.*word1)(?=.*word3).*$/gm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
/^(?=[\s\S]*\bword1\b)(?=[\s\S]*\bword3\b)/
```

- `[\s\S]` matches literally everything, encluding line wraps
- `\b` is the word bound, so `word1` count but `sword1` does not.

And since you treat all the lines as a whole, you dont need `m` flag

Also you're only testing the text, you don't need `g` flag either

```js
const text = `word1 in line1
     word2 in line2
  word3 in line 3`;
  
const regex = /^(?=[\s\S]*\bword1\b)(?=[\s\S]*\bword3\b)/;

console.log(regex.test(text));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regex alternation:

```regex
\bword1\b.*\bword3\b|\bword3\b.*\bword1\b
```

This matches `word1` anywhere followed by `word3`, or the reverse order.  Note that because JavaScript's regex engine does not support a dot all mode, we need to use `[\s\S]*` instead of `.*` to potentially match across newlines.

```js
var input = "word1 in line1\n     word2 in line2\n  word3 in line 3";
if (/\bword1\b[\s\S]*\bword3\b/.test(input) || /\bword3\b[\s\S]*\bword1\b/.test(input)) {
    console.log("MATCH");
}
else {
    console.log("NO MATCH");
}
```

Note that this pattern would potentially outperform the double positive lookahead version as in the best case scenario the former would require only a single scan of the input to find a match.  The double lookahead pattern, on the other hand, would always require two scans.